# How to handle bad input

Tags: java, dna-sequence

I'm trying to write a code that determines whether two inputs of DNA sequences are reverse compliments or not. The program asks the user to provide the sequences as a string. 
I have the code executing properly but I want to write a single `if` statement that continues the program if the characters are all 'A' 'T' 'C' or 'G'.

This is what i came up with on my own, but it doesnt work, and it doesn't even look close. I'm new to the language and come from ADA and am just stumped any help would be great.

```
if ( seqFirst.charAt(i) !=  'A' || seqFirst.charAt(i) != 'T' || 
                 seqFirst.charAt(i) != 'C' || seqFirst.charAt(i) != 'G' || 
                 seqSecond.charAt(i) !=  'A' || seqSecond.charAt(i) != 'T' || 
                 seqSecond.charAt(i) != 'C' || seqSecond.charAt(i) != 'G' )
```

Comment: So, it looks like you are trying to check whether any of the characters is wrong, here, and presumably, exit inside the *then clause*, right? You would need to use `and` here, instead of `or`, as @StephenC answered.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to change `||` to `&&` throughout the conditional expression.

By way of an explanation, consider this simplified version of your code:

```
  if (c != 'A' || c != 'T' ) { // IS BAD }
```

and consider the case where `c` is `'A'`.  The first predicate evaluates to `false`.  The second predicate evaluates to `true`.  The entire expression is `false || true` ... which is `true` ... "BAD"

Now change the `||` to `&&` and you get `false && true` ... which is `false` ... "NOT BAD"

---

> I'm new to the language and come from ADA ...

That's not the real problem.  The problem is understanding how boolean algebra works; i.e. [DeMorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).

Comment: @Reimeus @Brian     Alright so when i do `&&` it always says "not DNA" when i use `||` it always says is DNA

Comment: @A.Jarrett - You really need to understand the logic here.  Really.  Thoroughly.  If you don't understand it, you are liable to make the same mistake again.  1) Read / understand the link about DeMorgan's Laws.  2) Work it out for yourself by writing out the truth tables with a pencil and paper.

Comment: see I'm supposed to be in a class about it this semester, but it was full so.

Comment: @A.Jarrett - The "discrete math" class in your syllabus is (IMO) very important.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a possible De Morgan's Law issue.  Remember !(a or b) = !a and !b.

Comment: haven taken that class.

Comment: That's ok.  I'm saying either change all their ||'s (or) to &&. Or you can factor out the ! (Negation). Whatever is easier for you to understand.

Comment: if (!( seqFirst.charAt(i) ==  'A' || seqFirst.charAt(i) == 'T' || 
                 seqFirst.charAt(i) == 'C' || seqFirst.charAt(i) == 'G' || 
                 seqSecond.charAt(i) ==  'A' || seqSecond.charAt(i) == 'T' || 
                 seqSecond.charAt(i) == 'C' || seqSecond.charAt(i) == 'G' ))

Comment: Welcome to [so]! This is a comment, not an answer. Please edit to provide a useful answer so that you can gain enough rep to leave comments.

Answer (score 0):

As i know, 2 DNA string are reverse compliments when one of these equals to another, but reversed and with changed nucleotides. Since i dont know your version of Java, i wrote some readable method in Java7:

```
public static boolean isComplimentaryReverse(String str1, String str2) {
    //invalid input, could throw exception
    if (str1.length() != str2.length()) {
        return false;
    }
    //could be static final field
    Map<Character, Character> replaceTable = new HashMap<>();
    replaceTable.put('G', 'C');
    replaceTable.put('C', 'G');
    replaceTable.put('T', 'A');
    replaceTable.put('A', 'T');

    String reverseStr1 = new StringBuilder(str1).reverse().toString();
    for (int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++) {
        //invalid input, could throw exception
        if (!replaceTable.containsKey(reverseStr1.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        }
        if (str2.charAt(i) != replaceTable.get(reverseStr1.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify with a regular expression.

```
private static final String VALID_DNA = "[ATCG]+";
...

if (seqFirst.matches(VALID_DNA) && seqSecond.matches(VALID_DNA)) {
    // keep going...
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more, like i said I'm a rookie.

Comment: If you're not familiar with regular expressions, there's a wealth of information available through any search engine. In short, this checks your strings `seqFirst` and `seqSecond` and makes sure they are not empty and have only the letters A, T, C, or G in them.